# Excel Question, how can I make col D= last value in A before blank cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so I am working on this excel sheet, I have a problem in column D, I want to make D2= the last value in column A before null value.

Desired values in column D starting from D2

[image: Desired values in column D starting from D2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this formulas

first one put to d2 cell and drag it down

```
=IF(A2<>"";IF(A3<>"";D3;A2);"")
=IF(A3<>"";IF(A4<>"";D4;A3);"")
...
```

Comment: sadly its not working, it results in a value of "8" in all D cells

Comment: here is the link to working example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16RN99BMgkMk_3ElERWpBseNSjIYx9E2u/view

Answer (score 2):

For example in `D2` try:

```
=IF(A2<>"",INDEX(A2:$A$19,MATCH(TRUE,LEN(A2:$A$19)=0,0)-1),"")
```

Entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

and drag down...

If done correctly you'll get:

[image]

Comment: sadly its not working, the first one gives N/A. and the 2nd one results in a counter exactly like word_id column

Comment: @ElenaGT, in my answer I said to enter it as array formula... Don't just use enter, you must use Ctrl+Shift+Enter when you confirm the formula.

Comment: ok I didn't notice that sorry, but I did that now and it placed the formula in curly braces { }, but it resulted in all 0s.

Comment: Can you copy paste your formula in a comment @ElenaGT. As you can see in the added screenshot, the formula works just fine if done correctly.

Comment: {=IF(A2<>"";INDEX(A2:$A$19;MATCH(TRUE;LEN(A2:$A$19)=0;0)-1);"")} --> this is the exact formula im using but it results in N/A values so excel suggested this formula instead --->
{ =IF(A2<>"";INDEX($A$2:$A$19;MIN(IF(A2:$A$19="";ROW(A2:$A$19)-1)));"") } but it results in all 0s.
[both are entered as arrays, im using MAC excel v. 2018], any suggestions ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://exceljet.net/keyboard-shortcuts/enter-array-formula), hopefully that solves it.